# getting hour component from an NSDate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdatecomponents, nstimezone

I'm trying to get the hour component from an `NSDate`. 
Here is what I do:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+1"]];
    NSDateComponents *startComponents = [calendar components:DATE_COMPONENTS fromDate:_start];
    startComponents.timeZone =  [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+1"];
    int hours = [startComponents hour];
```

Now before yesterday the `hours value` always was one hour ahead. But since yesterday the `hours value` was 2 hours ahead.

I know this has something to do with the `NSTimezone` and the `DST`. But I can't get my head arround it!

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: probably timezone changed from GMT+1 to GMT+2 for european summer time... there exist methods to check if a date is within DST or not...

Comment: but it seems that when I try to set [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+2"] nothing changes.

Comment: might be due to the original date, but hard to tell without more information

Comment: Daylight Saving Time is a bitch, isn't it? :D

Comment: First determined if the NSDate object you're working with is "correct".  An NSDate is *supposed* to reflect UTC/GMT, and that's what you should see if you NSLog it.  If, when logged, the NSDate is local time, then you (oddly) need to set your NSCalendar to GMT to get the correct results.  (But consider Martin R's answer first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"GMT+1"` is not recognized as a time zone name, so that

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+1"]
```

is `nil` and the *local time zone* is used instead, which probably switched from Wintertime (GMT+01) to Summertime (GMT+02) last weekend in your country.

Replacing `"GMT+1"` with `"GMT+01"`:

```
[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT+01"]
// or alternatively:
[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:3600]
```

works and gives the expected result.

Note that it is sufficent to set the time zone of the `NSCalendar`. Setting the time zone
of the `NSDateComponents` has no effect in this case.