# Unix time stamp received from server using EEST timezone

Tags: ios, date, datetime, unix-timestamp

In my application i request certain date field from my server, the server returns values like :2014-06-03 00:00:00 EEST , but i need to load that data using GMT(GMT+2…) format, i am using the following code :

```
 double unixTimeStamp = [[date objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] doubleValue];
        NSTimeInterval _interval=unixTimeStamp;
        NSDate *dateToFinal = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
        NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
        _formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MMMM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz";
        [_formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"timeZone"]] ];
        [_formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
        dateFinal=[_formatter stringFromDate:dateToFinal];
      //      NSLog(@"Date Time < 3 %@" , dateFinal);
```

the user has the possibility to change his timezone, that's why when he saves it it's stored in a local cached variable , which i call in the previous code. But the most weird part is ,  if the user changes to GMT +1 or +2 or whatever, the application would still output the same hour time, which is 00:00, but if he changes to anything different from GMT, it will change. It's not normal to have GMT,GMT+1,GMT+4… to output the same hour which is 00:00. As a unix timestamp example we have 1401742800, which if u use an online time converter you would get Mon, 02 Jun 2014 21:00:00 GMT , but in the app its neither the same date nor time…what am i missing ?

Comment: "GMT+1" is not a valid time zone name, you have to use "GMT+01", compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/22765907/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR what should i change in my code thn